# Weblogic 10.3 issues with spring 3.1.0 jsp compilation

Tags: spring, jsp, weblogic-10.x

I have spring-webmvc 3.1.0.release version in my web-inf/lib folder of my warfile, but when the app is deployed to weblogic i am getting compilation errors.

weblogic is using spring 2.x version which comes bundled with weblogic 10.3.x to compile the jsps.

because of which i am getting compile time errors like setDynamicAttribute(null, String, String) is undefined for the type ErrorsTag

I tried using prefer-application-packages tag in weblogic.xml but it didn't work.

How do i resolve this?

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Are you deploying to a managed server or directly to an admin server? Is your server running in development mode or production mode? Do you have other applications deployed within the very same server instance?

Comment: I have similar issue, it looks like when it comes to JSP compiling, WAS doesn't consider `prefer-application-packages`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug - Weblogic 10.3.x doesn't consider `prefer-application-packages` when compiling JSP pages. Last checked on WAS 10.3.6.0

Comment: you mentioned a bug in Weblogic 10.3.X series, do you know any workarounds or any patches for WAS?

Comment: Sorry, no :( But haven't checked for some time.

Comment: It still continues and I can't update WAS installation. So I got stuck with this bug like you did :(

Comment: In this thread, apparently it worked: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2242698

Comment: According to official documentation: http://www.appservgrid.com/documentation/docs/fmw11g1114documentation/core.1111/e10105/trouble.htm#BABCDBAF

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476874/weblogic-10-3-5-overriding-spring-version

Answer (score 0):

I have tried  and its working on window machine successfully but didn't working on linux machine.

Below is my weblogic.xml file. if you are using window machine may be it will be helpful.

weblogic.xml

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">    
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.oracle.ojdbc16.*</package-name>
    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>  
</container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Thanks