# Spring Error in dynamic attributes

Tags: spring, weblogic, dynamic-attributes

I work with Eclipse Juno, Spring 3.2.6.RELEASE, Weblogic 10.3.6.

I have the following jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<form:form id="create-survey" method="POST" action="/eusurvey/noform/management/createNewSurvey" style="display: none">
<input type="hidden" name="shortname" id="create-survey-shortname" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="uuid" id="create-survey-uuid" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="original" id="create-survey-original" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="security" id="create-survey-security" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="audience" id="create-survey-audience" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="surveylanguage" id="create-survey-language" value="" />
<textarea style="display: none;" name="title" id="create-survey-title"></textarea>  
<input type="hidden" name="listform" id="create-survey-listform" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="contact" id="create-survey-contact" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="contactlabel" id="create-survey-contact-label" value="" />

</form:form>
```

When I execute the application, I get the error:

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /WEB-INF
/views/auth/tos.jsp
tos.jsp:79:21: Error in "menu.jsp" at line 358: The method 
setDynamicAttribute(null, String, String) is undefined for the type FormTag
        <%@ include file="../menu.jsp" %>   
                                     ^-----------^

at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:226)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:162)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:256)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:244)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:327)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
```

What does this error mean?. What are dynamic attributes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a classloading issue between your Spring and the one bundled into JRF.

Similar questions:

1. [Weblogic 10.3 issues with spring 3.1.0 jsp compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488270/weblogic-10-3-issues-with-spring-3-1-0-jsp-compilation)
2. [Weblogic 10.3.5 Overriding Spring Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476874/weblogic-10-3-5-overriding-spring-version)

It looks the quicker solution is to filter with **prefer-web-inf-classes** tag at **weblogic.xml**