# Weblogic Embedded Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I read in a forum that Weblogic comes with a version of Spring inside it, but I have been searching how to use that and I didn't find a way.

Is it true?

Is there a way to deploy a Spring application in Weblogic without put the jars related to Spring inside the application or in Weblogic's lib directory?

Thanks.

Comment: Not to my knowledge; what forum did you read this on?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476874/weblogic-10-3-5-overriding-spring-version

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17926847/2970947) implies it's JRF (rather then Weblogic proper). Also, SO is not a forum site.

Comment: Please. What is JRF? I tried in google, but I didn't find a proper result.

Comment: [Java Required Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13813/custom_jrf.htm): *Java Required Files (JRF) consists of those components not included in the WebLogic Server installation that provide common functionality for Oracle business applications and application frameworks.*

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. I tried to activate the JRF here, to do a test, but I got the same error in this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2175893?tstart=0   And I don't have another wlst.cmd in my instalation. Do I need a special instalation to have access to JRF resources?