# IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor when deploying application on weblogic server

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I developed a web application using spring version 3.2.6 and as long as I am deploying it on my tomcat server everything works fine.

Now, if I try to deploy this same application on a weblogic application server I get the following:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor
```

I think it is related to the spring version installed on the remote weblogic server.
I know I can force the server to use my classes by the following directive in the configuration xml:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>
        what do I put here?
    </package-name>
```

Anyway I really don't know what to set there...can you help me out?

Comment: Are the versions of Java different perhaps?

Comment: You think it is a java related problem? It should be the same version but in order to figure out I have to ask...unfortunately I have no control over the remote weblogic server :/

Comment: Possibly not actually, this thread has more information on this particular error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Answer (score 1):

Generally `IncompatibleClassChangeError` means that you have code changes without a recompile.

Use:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Or `prefer-web-inf-classes`

This will force weblogic to use the jar packaged in your app. If it still doesn't work, you have a separate issue.

Also check [this link about JRF versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476874/weblogic-10-3-5-overriding-spring-version)